# AD FS endpoints unavailable

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2012-r2

AD FS endpoints unavailable.
I configured AD FS. But when I try to connect to some endpoints, I can see "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."  The endpoints are enabled in the AD FS management.

I try to connect to
......adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed
and
...../services/trust/13/windowsmixed

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this happen from time to time.

Run the below command and see if the endpoint is listed. If not, reboot the server and check again.

```
netsh http sh serv | findstr /i /c:"trust/13/usernamemixed"
```

When you do you should see something like below if the endpoint is available.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh http sh serv | findstr /i /c:"trust/13/usernamemixed"
                HTTPS://+:443/ADFS/SERVICES/TRUST/13/USERNAMEMIXED/
```

Comment: Maweeras, thank you for answer.

When I run "netsh http sh serv | findstr /i /c:"trust/13/usernamemixed"", I can not see anything. Reboot couldn't help me.

I even ran only "netsh http sh serv" and checked manually. Same result.
 
Any ideas?

Comment: This is not quick. You need to raise a support incident with Microsoft. We need to see if the URL group is failing to register with HTTP.sys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give me an URL please where I can ask about it.

Comment: I was suggesting you get a paid support incident to investigate the server. Else you can wait and try of someone has the time to help you for free. If this is business impacting, a support case for immediate support is recommended

Comment: Maweeras, thank you for answer. I will take into account.

Comment: Looks like the latest . Net framework updates should resolve this apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with ADFS 2019.

There was an issue with AD FS service port, like Eugen had. After restarting AD FS service, the Event Viewer was showing error:

```
Event 102, AD FS

There was an error in enabling endpoints of Federation Service. Fix configuration errors using PowerShell cmdlets and restart the Federation Service.
Additional Data 
Exception details: 
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:808.
This could happen if there is another application already listening on this endpoint or if you have multiple
service endpoints in your service host with the same IP endpoint but with incompatible binding configurations. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionListener.Listen()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ExclusiveTcpTransportManager.OnOpen()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.ServiceHost.STSService.StartSTSService(ServiceHostManager serviceHostManager, ServiceState serviceState)
```

To fix the issue, you can change the service port follow the steps:

1. Launch SharePoint Management Shell as an administrator
2. Check current service port

   ```
   get-adfsproperties | findstr "NetTcpPort"
   NetTcpPort                                 : 1501
   ```
3. Change the service port

   ```
   Set-ADFSProperties -nettcpport 1601
   ```
4. Confirm change

   ```
   get-adfsproperties | findstr "NetTcpPort"
   NetTcpPort                                 : 1601
   ```
5. Restart AD FS service via Service console

Instructions are based on tech article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2009.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-change-the-net-tcp-ports-for-services-and-administration.aspx

Answer (score -3):

I have found solution.The problem was in port. The matter is the usual port for AD FS was busy.
You can find it [here](http://ea-code.com/Blog/Detail?id=1&author=Eugen%20Goroluov%20&date=February%2016,2017)

Comment: please explain the solution more in the answer not just sharing a link

Comment: Yep the link is dead. rather than posting the pertinent information as an answer he wrote it up in a blog, then stopped paying for his hosting costs

Comment: The answer @eastman gave appears to be the same. Another application holds the port in use and ADFS can't reserve it. You can either disable/move the existing application or move ADFS to a new port.